# In Sqlite database, How to Insert Multiple Rows in Table at same time

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

How we can insert multiple rows in Sqlite database at same time?  I'm using Android with Java.

Comment: In which programming language?

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is `bulkInsert`. It will allow you to supply an array of `ContentValues` to insert. See the Android docs for more info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#bulkInsert%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues%5B%5D%29

Comment: It is important to note that the documentation says: "This function make no guarantees about the atomicity of the insertions." But I could't find a better way to insert multiple rows.

Answer (score 5):

you can use inserthelper, check this [blog](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/)

Comment: `InsertHelper` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 2):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for(int i = 0; i<=5; i++) {
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, i);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, 0);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

Comment: is this efficient? can't you write all the rows with one request?

Answer (score 0):

Very old post however. When you are trying to do multiple calls to the db such as update or insert, wrap around with transactions. This will make a huge difference in speed.

```
db.beginTransaction();
try
{
    while(...) 
    {
        // .. do your inserts, updates and deletes here
    }

    // If successful commit those changes
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally 
{
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more on how does this affect?